# Can I exclude Exit Key while rebinding Vector2 keys in Unity's Input System?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input

I'm making rebind functions with Unity's Input System.
While checking the function, I found a problem which is in Vector2 key like Movement,
I want to can rebind esc key as new key value but Input System's internal script blocks it in InputActionRebindingExtensions.cs 2760 th line.

[image]

Is there any way to disable this limit?

I'm looking official documentation to solve this problem. Can anyone help me to provide a way to use 'WithControlsHavingToMatchPath' function?

Official Documentation Link: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.0/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputActionRebindingExtensions.RebindingOperation.html

Comment: hm why would you bind escape to a vector2 though? Maybe just have a second action for the escape button and in your code handle it accordingly .. e.g. `if(YourActions.Escape.inProgress){ use Vector2.zero here }`

Comment: Alternatively ... you can look at this extension method .. so you can also just implement the same method as a custom one and remove that limitation and instead of an extension simply call it directly

Comment: My project's immediate supervisor?(Sorry I'm not good at English) told me isn't is better to make that can desinate esc to vector2's value.
So I though like that.
Thanks for help